# How can I preserve line breaks while using regex Windows csv

Tags: regex, windows, csv, rapidminer

I am trying to keep rows in a csv file that match a certain string using regex in Rapidminer on a Windows 8 machine. I wrote regex that selects the right rows but the output does not retain line breaks and appears as a continuous string. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to keep the line breaks.

My file looks like this:

```
"ABCDEF","text",numbers,"JAN 1, 2014","text",numbers,10
"BCDEFG","text",numbers,"JAN 1, 2014","text",numbers,1
"CDEFGH","text",numbers,"FEB 1, 2014","text",numbers,12
"CDEFGH","text",numbers,"DEC 1, 2013","text",numbers,8
```

The following regexes select text from correct rows (1-3) but eliminate line breaks in output:

```
"[A-Z]*".*2014.*?(?=[\r\n$]+)
"[A-Z]*".*2014.*?(?=([\r\n]{2}))
"[A-Z]*".*2014.*?(?=([\r\n]{2}[\r\n$]*))
```

I tried multiline mode as well with the following regex, but with same result:

```
(?m)^"[A-Z]*".*2014.*?(?=[\r\n]+)$
```

My output looks like the following:

```
"ABCDEF","text",numbers,"JAN 1, 2014","text",numbers,10 "BCDEFG","text",numbers,"JAN 1, 2014","text",numbers,1 "CDEFGH","text",numbers,"FEB 1, 2014","text",numbers,12
```

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: With hwnd's and others' excellent suggestions, I came up with the following expression that worked in RapidMiner: (?m)^("[A-Z]+".*2014.*)\r\n

Comment: Don't use zero-width lookahead assertion, just match the line end.  Or add line breaks again when you join and write out the results.

Comment: Why don't you just use: `("[A-Z].*2014.*)`

Comment: Fede, thanks. This expression gives the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give a try to the following instead of using a lookahead assertion.

```
(?m)^"[A-Z]+".*2014.*$
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried both expressions. It is the same result. They do not preserve the line breaks.

Comment: I combined your suggestions with multiline mode. The following expression worked: (?m)^("[A-Z]+".*2014.*)\r\n   - Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the green tick, glad I could help.